# Match select2 on either label or option value

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a drop-down list to which I apply the [select2](https://select2.github.io/) enhancement. The list has option values as decimals (e.g. 6.25) and labels using fractional characters (e.g. 3¼). I would like the user to be able to type into the select2 box "3.25" and have it match against the label 3¼. How can this be done?

I have looked at the matcher function, but so far as I can tell, it is only given the labels to match against and not the option values. The source list looks something like this, and is quite long:

```
<select name="foo">
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="11.125">11⅛</option>
     <option value="11.25">11¼</option>
     <option value="11.375">11⅜</option>
     <option value="11.5">11½</option>
     ....
</select>
```

Matching against the key alone, will probably be enough.

Comment: Thinking about it, all the information I need *is* actually in the label, so a matcher function could decode the fractions into a decimal before doing a compare, but if I can avoid that decode, I would prefer that. The list may appear like "11¼" or may appear like "11-1/4", depending on uses in different places, so my preference is not to lock the solution on a specific option label format.